# Laravel: php -S localhost vs php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel

New to both PHP and Laravel. Getting my "`Hello, World!`" page up and kept getting a 404 "The requested resource / was not found on this server." error with Laravels included routing/view. I was using `php -S localhost:8000` for my local server and didn't realize I had to use Laravel's localhost (didn't even realize it had one) "php artisan serve" to host my page. My questions are:

- Is there an advantage to using `Laravel's localhost` vs `PHP's`?
- If I want to change how my localhost is, um, hosted, how do I do that? Example if I wanted to use PHP's built-in server vs Laravel's.

I'm pretty new to programming in general, let alone php/Laravel, so my apologies if this is a very basic question or one that doesn't even make sense. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

which also is the only difference between `artisan serve` and the standard php dev server. artisan serve simply adds the correct path to the server, there's no further magic involved.

Comment: As Michael said, you need to specify the correct location of the directory to serve (canonically, ./public from within your Laravel project's folder).

Comment: Great tip! This is now the only way to get good local logging under Laravel 9, `php artisan serve` broke it.